# JMeter body data in CSV

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am running some tests in JMeter and the accepted data has to be in the format as shown in the example below.

```
{
    "messageType": 1,
    "customerId": 5922429,
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "phone": "01234567890",
    "postcode": "PO6 3EN",
    "emailAddress": "joe.bloggs@example.com",
    "jobDescription": "do some stuff",
    "companyIds": [893999]
}
```

Now this works great but we want to randomise things up a little and read test data from a CSV file with about 20 samples.
Is this possible with the data having to be set out as above?
Currently the Body Data sits here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Modify your payload to rely on JMeter Variables like:

   ```
   {
     "messageType": ${messageType},
     "customerId": ${customerId},
     "name": "${name}",
     "phone": "${phone}",
     "postcode": "${postcode}",
     "emailAddress": "${emailAddress}",
     "jobDescription": "${jobDescription}",
     "companyIds": [${companyIds}]
   }
   ```

   once done you can put the values into a CSV file, like:

   ```
   messageType,customerId,name,phone,postcode,emailAddress,jobDescription,companyIds
   1,5922429,Joe Bloggs,01234567890,PO6 3EN,joe.bloggs@example.com,do some stuff,893999
   2,5922430,Jane Doe, 0987654321, P06 3EM,janedoe@example.com,do some other stuff,893998
   ```

   and read the data using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each virtual user will take the next line on each iteration and populate the body with the new values
2. If you have 20 different JSON files you can use [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin to load the file paths and [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read the data from the file in the file system